# equivalent of similarity in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, similarity

Postgresql has a function called similarity which it returns a number based on how similar two different words are. E.g similarity('postgre',postgra') it'll return 0.5.

Is there a similar function in redshift that does the same thing? There's a function called SIMILAR to but it returns boolean.

Comment: The best way to determine this is **test it** and see the results. While Redshift is based off Postgres it is based on an antique version ( 8.0? if  so initial release Jan 2005 final release Oct 2010).

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't have a built-in 'similarity' function.  The one you are finding is probably part of the pg_trgm extension.

As far as I can tell, redshift does not support extensions; there is no CREATE EXTENSION command [listed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_commands.html).

Answer (score 1):

The function `similarity()` in PostgreSQL is provided by the additional module `pg_trgm`.
Amazon Redshift does not support installing that module.

Redshift has the remotely related function [`difference()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/DIFFERENCE.html), based on the Soundex system, which really corresponds to PostgreSQL's function of the same name provided by the additional module [`fuzzystrmatch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html#id-1.11.7.24.6).